# Can I please have my photochemistry tag badge?

Tags: support

Bronze tag badges are seemingly created automatically and awarded once the requirements are met. The requirements are described in the [HelpCenter](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=bronze)
 as:

> You must have a total score of 100 in at least 20 non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge.

The mechanism has worked flawlessly on a couple of other tags but, unless I oversaw something, has failed for [photochemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photochemistry) despite a current total score of **111** on **42** non-wiki-answers.

Whether this results from some disturbances during site graduation or has other reasons is beyond my knowledge. Anyway, I'd like to see the issue solved.

Comment: Mission accomplished :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears that the reason it has not been awarded to you yet, is another criteria, from the [Tag Badges page](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=bronze), on the right-hand column, it says:

> These badges are awarded for participating in non community-wiki questions with particular tags. **If enough votes are earned in a tag with 100+ total questions**, the badge will be automatically created and awarded.

The [photchemistry tag](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photochemistry) has only 64 questions so far

Comment: I've definitely overlooked that.

Comment: It took me a while to find that information myself - it is not obvious at all.

Comment: I sense that as a big problem of SE. Anything about the sites that isn't in the help center is very hard to find out, even with a considerable amount of searching. Even though the Tag Badges page is some kinda  a help center itself.